# Trying to implement HTTP2 push

Tags: push, http2

From what I've read (which includes a Smashing mag article and an Akamai article) implementing HTTP2 server push consists of simply adding a header or two to the pages on my website. For example:

```
Link: </css/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style
Link: </js/common.js>; rel=preload; as=script
```

Is this accurate? Is it really that easy?

Comment: Testing tip: Don't use Fiddler to test it, it gets in between your browser and the server and breaks the HTTP2 connection. No HTTP2 - no push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely what web server you are running and how it implements HTTP/2 Push (if it does at all).

Using Link Headers works for Apache for example. Server push is not currently supported for Nginx. Some CDNs implement it with Link headers too.

However even if it is that easy to enable, you probably shouldn't without further thought. The problem is that while this will probably speed up the first load, and your JavaScript and CSS will be cached after that (you are caching your resources client side aren't you? If not then don't even look at advanced topics like HTTP/2 until you get the basics right). So if you push when its already cached it's a waste. Now a browser can stop a push, if it doesn't need that resource, because it already has it like in this example, but that still takes time and effort and for small resources (like CSS or JavaScript) it will likely have pretty much downloaded by the time you stop it.

So you should only push when there's a high chance the client will need the resource. [Cache-Digests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-digest-02) will be a way for the client to tell the server what resources it has cached, and so help the server to decide whether to push or not, however it's still a work in progress and not away if any browsers supporting it yet. In the meantime I've a simple cookie-based implementation here done in Apache, that might be of interest to you: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/http2-push/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've added a Link: header to my websites front page ( https://www.rgraph.net ) but according to the Initiator column in Chromes waterfall chart the download of styles.css is not triggered by push. Though having said that if I change the URL in the Link: header to something that doesn't exist it does result in a 404 occurring in the list of requests (in the network panel). So maybe it is working - maybe not.

Comment: The asset you're using needs to be used by the page. Looking at your site you are trying to push foo.css but 1) that does not exist and 2) it's not referenced anywhere on your html so is pointless being pushed.

Comment: That was just a test. The thing that I really want to push is styles.css - so I've added this PHP to add the Link header: header('Link: </css/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style'); The header is being sent OK and I can see that in the Chrome  network panel - but the initiator is not mentioning "Push".

Comment: Looks right now but agree it's not working. What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: Your server supports NPN as shown by https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.rgraph.net. Apache does not. So you must have something in front of Apache which is what is handling the HTTP/2. It presumably does not support push by Link headers.

Comment: Thanks for looking - I've been looking for the version used by my shared hosting but not found it. ServerTokens directive isn't working - nor is /server-info. I think 1and1 must have it locked down pretty well. The website is pretty reasonable (performance-wise) anyway... :-/